# ASP.NET and Knockout.JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've got an api that provides data about persons, such as:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudId { get; set; }
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public decimal Nota { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get data from this api using Knockout and fill a table with it (I'm starting with small things, but I'd appreciate all the help you guys can provide ).

```
 // Function to fill the students
    function studentModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.students = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON("/api/student", function (data) {
            self.students(data);
        })
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new studentModel());
```

Table:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: students">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Nume</th><th>Prenume</th><th>Data</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: StudId"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Nume"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Prenume"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Data"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html. Sorry, you can't expect other people to write your code for you without showing some effort.

Comment: I've tried multiple times, but I'm failing again and again... I got a JSON by the model  mentioned above and I'm trying to place it in an observableArray, but it simply doesnt work...
I dont want someone to write code for me, I need some indications

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have written? What do you mean by simply doesn't work?

Comment: @MaheshWarrier I've posted it, buddy. But no data is being added to the table. I've tested it with postman and im receiving students from the table. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code looks fine from what I see. Do you see errors in the browser console?

Comment: Can't see any errors

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `foreach`, it needs to be on the tr, not table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th><th>Nume</th><th>Prenume</th><th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: StudId"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Nume"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Prenume"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezjj8dma/

Comment: Well, it seems to be because of the database... Just noticed that when im trying to open it, it shows an "The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information: ... " error message. Anyone knows whats goin on ?

Comment: Nvm , I fixed it... Thank you guys, anyways.

Comment: Does anyone know how to send a DELETE request using knockout?